# How do I run gnome-desktop via TightVNC on an AWS server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, gnome, ubuntu-20.04, vnc

I want to use an AWS Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server with GNOME desktop/Unity over VNC. While I can connect via VNC, I get a bare bones, gray X window. In some variations, I also had a poorly drawn file manager.
Currently, I have `tightvncserver` installed, with a password set. I launch it as:
`vncserver :1`. I'm connecting from a Windows 10 box, running TightVNC Viewer.

It very much seems that the X11 display manager is the problem, not VNC. However, the `gdm3` display manager is running:

```
$ systemctl status display-manager.service
● gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-04-29 14:53:51 UTC; 32min ago
    Process: 17105 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/gdm/generate-config (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 17113 ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wait-for-drm (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 17163 (gdm3)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 18978)
     Memory: 6.2M
     CGroup: /system.slice/gdm.service
             └─17163 /usr/sbin/gdm3

Apr 29 14:53:40 ip-10-0-1-105 systemd[1]: Starting GNOME Display Manager...
Apr 29 14:53:51 ip-10-0-1-105 systemd[1]: Started GNOME Display Manager.
Apr 29 14:53:51 ip-10-0-1-105 gdm-launch-environment][17177]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened >
Apr 29 14:53:51 ip-10-0-1-105 gdm-launch-environment][17177]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session closed >
Apr 29 14:53:51 ip-10-0-1-105 gdm3[17163]: GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing
Apr 29 14:53:51 ip-10-0-1-105 gdm3[17163]: Child process -17271 was already dead.
Apr 29 14:53:51 ip-10-0-1-105 gdm3[17163]: Child process -17271 was already dead.
Apr 29 14:53:51 ip-10-0-1-105 gdm-launch-environment][17706]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened >
lines 1-19/19 (END)
```

I have tried the following instructions:

1. [VNC connection to Linux VM jus shows a gray screen... bu isn't gnome running?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233276/vnc-connection-to-a-linux-vm-just-shows-a-gray-screen-but-isnt-gnome-running)
2. [Ubuntu 20.04 Remote Desktop Access with VNC](https://www.answertopia.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-remote-desktop-access-with-vnc/)
3. [How to Install and Configure VNC on Ubuntu 20.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-20-04)
4. [How to run Gnome desktop on Ubuntu 20.04 in cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63488139/how-to-run-gnome-desktop-on-ubuntu-20-04-in-cloud)
5. [Installing and configuring Ubuntu Desktop for Google Cloud Platform](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781788474221/1/ch01lvl1sec15/installing-and-configuring-ubuntu-desktop-for-google-cloud-platform) - Yes, this is about Google Cloud, but the prior item refers to it as a solution.

There are probably 6 others that I have also tried. I don't have their URLs handy, nor do I think them particularly helpful since the results are virtually identical.

This is not new and doesn't seem like it should be this hard. I never even get a session authentication prompt. I *am* willing to start again from scratch with a new Ubuntu 20.04 AWS server if that will help to clean up any mistakes/unknown conditions.

While I have had numerous iterations of `~/.vnc/xstartup`, it currently looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -sold grey
xterminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
export XKL_MODEMAP_DISABLE=1
/etc/X11/Xsession
```

While `/etc/X11/Xsession` is the default:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# /etc/X11/Xsession
#
# global Xsession file -- used by display managers and xinit (startx)

# $Id: Xsession 967 2005-12-27 07:20:55Z dnusinow $

set -e

PROGNAME=Xsession

message () {
  # pretty-print messages of arbitrary length; use xmessage if it
  # is available and $DISPLAY is set
  MESSAGE="$PROGNAME: $*"
  echo "$MESSAGE" | fold -s -w ${COLUMNS:-80} >&2
  if [ -n "$DISPLAY" ] && which xmessage > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "$MESSAGE" | fold -s -w ${COLUMNS:-80} | xmessage -center -file -
  fi
}

message_nonl () {
  # pretty-print messages of arbitrary length (no trailing newline); use
  # xmessage if it is available and $DISPLAY is set
  MESSAGE="$PROGNAME: $*"
  echo -n "$MESSAGE" | fold -s -w ${COLUMNS:-80} >&2;
  if [ -n "$DISPLAY" ] && which xmessage > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo -n "$MESSAGE" | fold -s -w ${COLUMNS:-80} | xmessage -center -file -
  fi
}

errormsg () {
  # exit script with error
  message "$*"
  exit 1
}

internal_errormsg () {
  # exit script with error; essentially a "THIS SHOULD NEVER HAPPEN" message
  # One big call to message() for the sake of xmessage; if we had two then
  # the user would have dismissed the error we want reported before seeing the
  # request to report it.
  errormsg "$*" \
           "Please report the installed version of the \"x11-common\"" \
           "package and the complete text of this error message to" \
           "<debian-x@lists.debian.org>."
}

# initialize variables for use by all session scripts

OPTIONFILE=/etc/X11/Xsession.options

SYSRESOURCES=/etc/X11/Xresources
USRRESOURCES=$HOME/.Xresources

SYSSESSIONDIR=/etc/X11/Xsession.d
USERXSESSION=$HOME/.xsession
USERXSESSIONRC=$HOME/.xsessionrc
ALTUSERXSESSION=$HOME/.Xsession
ERRFILE=$HOME/.xsession-errors

# attempt to create an error file; abort if we cannot
if (umask 077 && touch "$ERRFILE") 2> /dev/null && [ -w "$ERRFILE" ] &&
  [ ! -L "$ERRFILE" ]; then
  chmod 600 "$ERRFILE"
elif ERRFILE=$(tempfile 2> /dev/null); then
  if ! ln -sf "$ERRFILE" "${TMPDIR:=/tmp}/xsession-$USER"; then
    message "warning: unable to symlink \"$TMPDIR/xsession-$USER\" to" \
             "\"$ERRFILE\"; look for session log/errors in" \
             "\"$TMPDIR/xsession-$USER\"."
  fi
else
  errormsg "unable to create X session log/error file; aborting."
fi

# truncate ERRFILE if it is too big to avoid disk usage DoS
if [ "`stat -c%s \"$ERRFILE\"`" -gt 500000 ]; then
  T=`mktemp -p "$HOME"`
  tail -c 500000 "$ERRFILE" > "$T" && mv -f "$T" "$ERRFILE" || rm -f "$T"
fi

exec >>"$ERRFILE" 2>&1

echo "$PROGNAME: X session started for $LOGNAME at $(date)"

# sanity check; is our session script directory present?
if [ ! -d "$SYSSESSIONDIR" ]; then
  errormsg "no \"$SYSSESSIONDIR\" directory found; aborting."
fi

# Attempt to create a file of non-zero length in /tmp; a full filesystem can
# cause mysterious X session failures.  We do not use touch, :, or test -w
# because they won't actually create a file with contents.  We also let standard
# error from tempfile and echo go to the error file to aid the user in
# determining what went wrong.
WRITE_TEST=$(tempfile)
if ! echo "*" >>"$WRITE_TEST"; then
  message "warning: unable to write to ${WRITE_TEST%/*}; X session may exit" \
          "with an error"
fi
rm -f "$WRITE_TEST"

# use run-parts to source every file in the session directory; we source
# instead of executing so that the variables and functions defined above
# are available to the scripts, and so that they can pass variables to each
# other
SESSIONFILES=$(run-parts --list $SYSSESSIONDIR)
if [ -n "$SESSIONFILES" ]; then
  set +e
  for SESSIONFILE in $SESSIONFILES; do
    . $SESSIONFILE
  done
  set -e
fi

exit 0
```

In case it is relevant, below is the list of current `systemctl` targets. Note that `graphical-target` is active. I've also tried with `multi-user` as the default target. I don't observe any change.

```
$ systemctl get-default
multi-user.target
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-105:~$ systemctl list-units --type target --state active
  UNIT                   LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
  basic.target           loaded active active Basic System
  cloud-config.target    loaded active active Cloud-config availability
  cloud-init.target      loaded active active Cloud-init target
  cryptsetup.target      loaded active active Local Encrypted Volumes
  getty.target           loaded active active Login Prompts
  graphical.target       loaded active active Graphical Interface
  local-fs-pre.target    loaded active active Local File Systems (Pre)
  local-fs.target        loaded active active Local File Systems
  multi-user.target      loaded active active Multi-User System
  network-online.target  loaded active active Network is Online
  network-pre.target     loaded active active Network (Pre)
  network.target         loaded active active Network
  nss-lookup.target      loaded active active Host and Network Name Lookups
  nss-user-lookup.target loaded active active User and Group Name Lookups
  paths.target           loaded active active Paths
  remote-fs-pre.target   loaded active active Remote File Systems (Pre)
  remote-fs.target       loaded active active Remote File Systems
  slices.target          loaded active active Slices
  sockets.target         loaded active active Sockets
  swap.target            loaded active active Swap
  sysinit.target         loaded active active System Initialization
  time-set.target        loaded active active System Time Set
  time-sync.target       loaded active active System Time Synchronized
  timers.target          loaded active active Timers

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

24 loaded units listed.
```

Comment: "This is not new and doesn't seem like it should be this hard." 100% agree.